# Outlook events bullk deletion using MS Flows

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, ms-flow

My requirement is delete all events from outlook using MS Flows.

I have tried with below mentioned steps.

select --> Outlook 365 
--> add, update or modified Outlook events
--> select calendar --> Calendar
--> ID __> in Id place i have provided Subject name(It might be wrong)

if condition
yes --> delete event v2
no--> Notification

But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

- Use button as trigger (you can run on demand)
- Get events - you could use Filter Query to
  narrow it down the results or use a conditional inside the 'Apply to
  each' loop
- Delete the Event
- Send notification
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to delete events you are required to provide the ID of the calendar event.

You could add a custom column (Event ID column) within your SharePoint list to store the 
Outlook Event Id of the new created event.

Detailed steps you can refer to this similar situation below:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/How-to-delete-calendar-event-using-microsoft-flow/td-p/113739